# Prove or disprove (Real numbers)

Tags: trigonometry, real-numbers

Show that for every $\theta$ $\in (0, π/2)$, there exists a unique real
$x_θ$ such that $$(\sin \theta)^{x_θ} + (\cos \theta)^{x_θ} = \frac{3}{2}$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(\sin\theta)^0+(\cos\theta)^0=2$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\sin\theta)^x+(\cos\theta)^x=0$ (notice that $\sin\theta<1$ and $\cos\theta<1$), by intermediate value theorem, there is $x_\theta$ such that $(\sin\theta)^{x_\theta}+(\cos\theta)^{x_\theta}=\frac32$ for every $\theta\in(0,\pi)$.

Since $x\mapsto(\sin\theta)^x+(\cos\theta)^x$ is monotonically decreasing, such an $x_\theta$ must be unique.

---

Hope this helps.